# Allow both CSS modules and imports

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I'm pretty new to Webpack. Basically right now it's set up to support React css-modules. However, I'd like it to also support just plain imports, like

```
import classes from './My-Classes.scss'
```

&

```
import './My-Other-Classes.scss'
```

For the former, I have

```
{ test: /\.scss$/, loader: 'style!css?modules&importLoaders=2&sourceMap&localIdentName=[local]___[hash:base64:5]!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 version!sass?outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap' },
```

Is it possible to allow both styles of importing, and if so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: why are you importing your scss files?

Comment: @JohnRuddell I should mention this is ReactJS.

Comment: I get that you are using react. I use it all the time. I just don't see the point in importing your scss file. you should have it all compiled to one file that gets statically loaded via html

Comment: @JohnRuddell Agree to disagree I guess. I find this much more organized.

Comment: so you are importing your scss files in every react component? and then doing what with it?

Comment: @JohnRuddell When CSS modules are used, you then do `className={ classes.myCssClass }`. Here's a starter kit that uses this technique: https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your web pack config file :

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css']
      }
    ]
  }
```

You will need to add these modules to your package.json :

```
css-loader
sass-loader
style-loader
```

Comment: Try to replace your code with mine. It Works for me